# How to automate the scale of an application in C #

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, resolution

I made a program in Windows format in C # with a resolution of 1920 x 1080 and a scale of 100%, but when I open this program on another computer, all the controls fall apart.
I want to know if I can do something that did not happen when I run the program on another computer?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the controls fall apart"? It's hard for us to guess.

Comment: FYI, WPF uses  Device-Independent Units (DIPs) to avoid this problem. https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/02/19/759-device-independent-units-dips/

Comment: use Dock (Form) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/winforms-scaling-at-large-dpi-settings-is-it-even-possible- | read the `General Tips for Designing Scalable WinForms`

Comment: Not enough information is provided to answer effectively. Can you include some links to screenshots in order to understand better what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [Dock and Anchor controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-dock-and-anchor?view=netdesktop-6.0) and also use `FlowLayoutPanel`, `TableLayoutPanel` and other types of container controls to [Position and layout of controls (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/layout?view=netdesktop-6.0).

If you use the techniques described in these links, your controls will resize to fit other window sizes without having to scale anything.

Comment: Maybe the _op_ is talking about font scaling and not window sizing.

Comment: @JAlex, the problem seems not to be a different system font size but a different screen resolution (i.e., a smaller screen).

Comment: I was going the other way, with the second monitor having a higher resolution, and a font scaling > 100%. So a label which might be 24pixels tall on the first monitor will end up being 36pixels high with 150% font scaling, since the default mode for forms is "scale with fonts".